# DB Where Condition Based on Alphabetical Comparison of 2 columns

Tags: postgresql, sorting, conditional-statements, where-clause, alphabetical

I have SQL query of self Join **products** table

id | product_name

I need to make 2 sets:

A vs B and B vs A.

A vs B means alphabetically first will come first.

B vs A means alphabetically first will come last.

Following giving all combinations with a's id less than b'id but I need based on alphabetically first

```
SELECT
a.product_name || b.product_name
from 
products a
JOIN products b ON a.id != b.id  -- same product combination not needed 
WHERE
   a.id < b.id
```

Sample Data

```
1 | Apple
2 | Apricots
3 | Bananas
4 | Blueberries
5 | Cherries
6 | Cucumbers
7 | Dates
8 | Dragon Fruit
9 | Eggfruit
10 | Mango
```

Total set will have Every fruit will have combination with every one without where condition.

I need 2 separate sets.

First set will have: A vs B - Alphabetically First

```
Apple Vs Apricots
```

Second set will have: B Vs A - Alphabetically last

```
Apricots Vs Apple
```

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results and info on your collation settings.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: @Nick : I need 2 separate sets from whole comparisons as it is getting duplicate. Need alphabetically ordered and alphabetically reverse.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt: Added sample data

Comment: @SomnathMuluk something like this? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/62fef/9

Comment: @Nick : This is not giving 2 sets. < or > is not giving alphabetical which product is first. Isn't it?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk there are two sets of data there, the first ends with `Eggfruit - Mango`. I've updated the demo with a `set1` column to make it more obvious http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/62fef/11

Comment: @Nick: Got it. Can we get 2 separate resultsset. Like 2 queries. 1 query will return first set and 2nd query will give 2nd set. Please post this as answer. So that I can accept answer.

Comment: Actually I checked a.product_name < b.product_name, this was giving correct results, which I had ignored. :( Which I had added in description. So I am removing that from description. So it can work on Join or on where condition too. But Join will be more good as it will be less time consuming. @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two queries to get the two result sets you want, they are fundamentally the same with just the `JOIN` condition being changed for the second query:

```
SELECT a.product_name || ' - ' ||  b.product_name AS products
FROM products a
JOIN products b ON a.product_name < b.product_name
ORDER BY a.product_name, b.product_name
```

For the second query the `JOIN` condition is:

```
JOIN products b ON a.product_name > b.product_name
```

Output (for first query):

```
Apple - Apricots
Apple - Bananas
Apple - Blueberries
...
Dragon Fruit - Eggfruit
Dragon Fruit - Mango
Eggfruit - Mango
```

Output (for second query):

```
Apricots - Apple
Bananas - Apple
Bananas - Apricots
...
Mango - Dates
Mango - Dragon Fruit
Mango - Eggfruit
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/62fef/15)